# Why cannot I compile `\documentclass{minimal}\document . \enddocument` ?

Tags: compiling

Why cannot I compile the most minimal code below?

```
\documentclass{minimal}\document . \enddocument
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The usual LaTeX `\begin ... \end` construct forms a group. However, this is not the case for the `document` environment. To do this, `\document` closes the group that `\begin` has opened, and `\enddocument` starts a group which `\end` then closes. So

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begingroup
\document
a 
\enddocument
\endgroup
```

does compile (though I would not recommend it!).

(LaTeX3 note: environments generated by [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) include a proper internal macro for the two ends, and so a LaTeX3 kernel will *not* expose the start and end macros in this way.)

Comment: Is there any reason why `document` should not form a group?

Comment: @Caramdir: The reason is efficiency. If an assignment happens inside a group, TeX has to remember the previous value in order to restore it after the group ends, which consumes time and memory. Since nothing happens after `\end{document}`, it makes sense to make the document body global.

Comment: @Joseph: Can you elaborate a bit on your final parenthetical? What do you mean by a proper internal macro?

Comment: @TH. Seems like a separate item to the question here: see my blog post at http://www.texdev.net/2011/01/09/latex3-and-document-environments/

Comment: @Joseph: Ah ha, now I understand what you mean, thanks. I'm curious how that will interact with the situations in LaTeX2e that require one to use `\foo` and `\endfoo` directly. Hopefully those situations won't arise in LaTeX3.